# Cannot find/delete local branch with "è" in branchname

Tags: git

I accidentally created a local branch `issue-1299è`. When I do `git branch`, you can see the branch.

[image]

But when I do `git branch -D issue-1299è`, the branch is not found...

[image]

Any good practice around this?

Comment: Go into the .git folder, refs, and see if you can find the actual file referring to the branch, see if that gives you something you can copy/paste that will match.

Comment: have you tried quoting the branch name git branch -D "issue-1299è"

Comment: are you at windows?

Comment: I'm using macOS High Sierra. @max630

Comment: When I quote the branchname, I got the same error: "branch 'issue-1299è' not found." @Newtopian

Comment: There was no matching file in the ".git/refs" folder. But there is a reference in ".git/packed-refs" file. @LasseVågsætherKarlsen

Comment: Did the torek's answer help? If it did not I believe it is mostly ok to remove it from the ".git/packed-refs"

Comment: You may want to save the line from packed-refs and report it to the git mailing list (see https://git-scm.com/community ).

Comment: torek's answer was a bit hard for me. I'll check out the git mailing list. Thanks for your input @max630!

Answer (score 1):

The character *shows* as LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH GRAVE (see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e8/index.htm). However, there are multiple ways to encode this character.  Even if you are using UTF-8, it may be represented as U+00C8, or as the *decomposed form*, LATIN SMALL LETTER E U+0065 followed by COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT U+0300 (see the linked Unicode page).

Git itself doesn't know all this, it just deals in byte strings.  If you type in one of the two byte strings that displays as è when the actual encoding uses the other one, Git won't find the one you typed in.  (This particular issue is annoying and difficult and is not limited to Git.)

You can use `git for-each-ref` to iterate over all the references, obtaining their byte-code strings, programmatically, and then use that to delete the byte-coded string that you want to get rid of.  [Igor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48343136/1256452) is simpler though, and probably sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux and this is the only branch with name starting with "issue-1299", you could try the following command.

```
git branch -D `git branch | LC_ALL=C grep 'issue-1299.*'`
```

It will find the branch with the name starting with "issue-1299" and delete it.

Comment: I still got the error: "branch 'issue-1299è' not found."

Answer (score 0):

I removed the reference `refs/heads/issue-1299è` in the file `.git/packed-refs`.

There was no matching file at the path `refs/heads/issue-1299è`.

So, this solved my problem.

Thanks everyone! I really appreciate your help!